# How should streak badges be awarded in edge cases (like StackOverflow badges)?

Tags: users, gamification, badge

I am brainstorming how to create streak badges like StackOverflow badges. For example, (I will just make some up), if you vote 30 times a day for 5 days straight, you get a `vote30x5day` badge, or if create a post 100 times in a month, you get a `post100x1month` badge.

The question is, say you have a limit of 1000 posts per month, and 50 posts per day. Say you create 100 posts in 2 days. Then you technically hit the mark for a badge. Now, first question, should you get the badge now, or only after a month has past from when you first hit the streak? If you get it now, what if you then delete a post? Ideally it shouldn't remove badges, so this means likely you want to have to wait until 1 month passes before you see if you got the badge. Maybe there is some indicator like "on track to receiving `post100x1month` badge (1 month means 30 days)!", unless you delete a post, then it goes away. Only after 1 month of having 100 posts do you finally get the `post100x1month` badge.

Does that part make sense?

Then, say you get to 200 posts in the first 4 days! You could technically then delete 101 posts, to take you back to 99 posts below any badge mark. But in theory should it say "on track for 2 badges"? Say they hit 100 posts on day 2 and 200 posts on day 4, and now it is day 4. Should it say "on track to receiving a `post100x1month` badge in 28 days (from the 2 days ago one), and on track to receiving a `post100x1month` badge in 30 days (from today)"? Like, should you be able to get more than one badge of `post100x1month` type in a month? Or does everything you do after hitting 100 in the first two days not count for anything, and you must wait until the next month before it starts counting again?

I'm not quite sure how this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that it all comes down to the language used to describe the achievement.

If the achievement is "Create a post 100 times in a month" then I would expect to be rewarded as soon as that criteria is met. Even if I delete 99 of my 100 posts, I still created 100 posts and therefore met the requirements for the reward.

If you'd prefer to reward them at the end of the month, adjust the language accordingly. "Have 100 new posts at the end of the month"

Comment: Good idea, thank you!